# Positioning Widgets in a Specific Arrangment

Tags: android, layout, positioning

I'm quite new with Android programming in general, but I would like to know if there is a way to arrange my widgets in a particular way. Basically, I'm looking for the iOS equivalent of constraints, which will allow me to place to widgets centered horizontally and a specified distance from the bottom:

```
--------------------
|                  |
|                  | 
|                  |   <- android device
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |   <- x is a button
|        x x       |
|                  |
--------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a RelativeLayout with alignParentBottom="true"
Then you can add a padding in your relativelayout or a margin in your buttons a bit like this.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation:"horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <Button 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <Button 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This centers the two buttons on top of one another and it doesn't bring them to the bottom.

Comment: Ow ok Two buttons [Edited]